# Specify commit template for a remote git repository

Tags: git

You can obviously use `git.config` to create a [commit template](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#idp31225376) for your local repository. Is it possible to set this on your remote repository so that someone who clones the repository will inherit the commit template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to install templates automatically, but there are a few things you can do:

- You can distribute your commit templates in the repository and include either documentation on how to install them or a script to install them automatically.  This also works well for things like local git hooks.
- You can implement a hook on your remote repository that will reject commits that don't use the template (which will encourage people to use the documentation or script you provided in the earlier bullet point)